# Widget looks different on different phones

Tags: android, widget

I have huge problem with my widgets. The problem is it looks different on different phones. Let me show you examples.

It should looks like this (on SGS2 with Android 4.3.1):
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/rno895pfcvp6t33/SGS2.png

On Galaxy Ace (with Android 2.3.3) there is little empty gap:
https://dl.dropbox.com/s/woe15ten9qxoq4f/SGAce.png

Finally my friends phone (sony xperia tipo) with Android 4.1 (same resolution like Galaxy Ace one):
https://dl.dropbox.com/s/admfg3tht3zxtzh/WDuOieP.png

Here is provider of big widget:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appwidget-provider 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/widget_days_big"
    android:minHeight="162dp"
    android:minWidth="300dp"
    android:updatePeriodMillis="1800000" >
</appwidget-provider>
```

Any ideas why something like this occurs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should read this first carefully: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/widget_design.html

(Columns or Rows)

```
            Available Size (dp)     (minWidth or minHeight)

                      1               40dp
                      2               110dp
                      3               180dp
                      4               250dp
```

Take into consideration different dpi's/resolutions/screen sizes, some phones might not have a screen "fit enough" to display the widget of your size -> minWidth 300dp....

What you are experiencing is normal behavior, you need to open your widgets xml layout and pay more attention to font size, paddings, margins etc... unfortuantelly you need to make the layout xml "properly" and test it, keep in mind you have ldpi,mdpi,hdpi,xhdpi layouts to help you if your widget doesnt turn out right on all phones with default layout.